# Search inside a collection based on a given list of items

Tags: c#, linq, search

Lets say I am given a list as input:

```
IList<string> availableFruits = {orange, banana}
```

I have a fruit entity that looks like this:

```
public Fruit 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

we define some fruits:

```
var f1 = new Fruit { Id = 1, name = "apple" };
var f2 = new Fruit { Id = 2, name = "banana" };
var f3 = new Fruit { Id = 3, name = "orange" };
var f4 = new Fruit { Id = 4, name = "pineapple" };
```

Finally, we have a menu where these fruits go:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fruit> fruits;
}

var menus = new List<Menu>
{
    new Menu {ID = 0, fruits = new List<Fruit> { f1, f2 } },
    new Menu {ID = 1, fruits = new List<Fruit> { f1, f3, f4 } },
    new Menu {ID = 2, fruits = new List<Fruit> { f1, f4 } },
    new Menu {ID = 3, fruits = new List<Fruit> { f2 } },
};
```

I need a LINQ query that searches in the menus and returns all menus that contains 'ANY' of the fruits passed in the avaiableFruits list. Thus in this case it will return menus with ID's 0, 1 and 3.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Post your efforts and what is not working for you.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a few things but left those details out to keep the question easy to follow

Comment: You should post what you've tried.  SO is not here to do your work for you, but rather to help you get unstuck from something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See it in this way: keeps the menus that any of the fruit in `fruits` property is in `availableFruits`:

```
var availables = menus.Where(m => m.fruits.Any(f => availableFruits.Contains(f.name)));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had something similar going but just couldn't wrap my mind around with use of  Any and Contains together...

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<Menu> select_menus(IEnumerable<Menu> menus, IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits) {
   return menus.Where(m => m.fruits.Intersect(fruits).Any());
}
```